# centering form with css with position absolute

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center this form

[image]

here is my css:

```
form {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

The form will center if I get rid of position absolute however if I remove position absolute the following happens

[image]

Can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute)** takes the element out of the flow.

If you want to apply **[`margins`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)**, you'll want to make use of **[`position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#relative)**:

```css
form {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<form>Form</form>
```

If you have to use an absolutely-positioned element, you can make use of **[`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left)** in combination with **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** to offset the element by `50%` minus half of its **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)**:

```css
form {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  left: calc(50% - (400px/2));
}
```

```html
<form>Form</form>
```

Comment: I want position absolute to take the form out of the normal flow of the page so that my navigation bar doesn't follow. I tried position relative but I have the same issue as shown in the second picture.

Comment: In that case, assuming you **know** the width of the element, you can use `left` to offset it. You'll want a value that is `50%` minus half of the width of the element. This can be achieved with `calc()`. I've updated my answer to show this :)

Comment: I see I didn't realize that margin:auto wouldn't work with position absolute. Thank you it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block;` to the `form`. And wrapp it with a `div` (or other `display: block;` element) and add `text-align: center` to the `div`.

This way you will center it, with no hard coded values. If the width of you divs vary, it will center automatically.

```css
div {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    input: <input/> <br>
    other: <input/> <br>  
    <button>SUBMIT</button>
  </form>
</div>
```